# Checker framework - problem with MapStruct converters

Tags: java, spring, converters, mapstruct, checker-framework

I am trying to add checker framework's Nullness checker to our project, however I am having problem with our MapStruct converters.

### Converter example

Lets say I have a converter from User to UserDto like following:

```
@MapperConfig(componentModel = SPRING)
public interface UserToUserDtoConverter 
    extends org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<User, UserDto> {
}
```

Which generates the following implementation:

```
@Override
public UserDto convert(User source) {
    if ( source == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    UserDtoBuilder<?, ?> userDto = UserDto.builder();
    userDto.id(source.getId());
    
    return userDto.build();
}
```

### Problem

Now the problem is that Checker framework complains about the `return null;`, as the implementation does not have @Nullable above the convert method.

Another problem is when the converter uses other converters that are autowired here, which results in initialization.field.uninitialized error.

### Things I have tried

Now I know that I could simply ignore converters completely with -AskipDefs, however I would still like it to let it check that there won't be a problem with assigning @Nullable value from User to @NonNull value in UserDto (and vice versa, which could leave a hole in the project).

Another solution that came to my mind was adding @SuppressWarning annotation for these error codes in the converter interface, however mapstruct is not capable of propagating any annotation to the implementation if I am not mistaken [mapstruct-issues](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1574).

Stub files won't help here either.

Is here some kind of solution for handling the generated code?

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem?  It seems correct that the Nullness Checker complains about `return null;`, because that return statement is indeed inconsistent with the method signature whose return type is (non-null) `UserDto`.  Do you know that the method will never return null?  Are you trying to suppress the warning, to provide a different signature for the method, or something else?

Comment: @mernst Thank you for the reply. It is alright that the method can return null if the input is also null. Ideally I would like to provide \@PolyNull annotation to the method (input parameter + return value), however I am not sure how to do that, as it is generated. Simple suppression of warnings would be also acceptable (if only warning for returning of null would be suppressed together with possibly non-initialized \@Autowired converters).

Comment: So I could put my questions like this:

1) Is there a way to force MapStruct to insert checker-framework annotation to the generated converter class.

2) If not, is there any other way to ignore only [return] and [initialization.field.uninitialized] error codes in the scope of generated converters (while still keeping other checker-framework errors codes like passing @Nullable variable to @NonNull).

Comment: Regarding #1, I suggest you post a new question to ask it.
Regarding #2, the Checker Framework has a variety of ways to [suppress warnings](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings).  There isn't currently a way to scope a suppression to a single class.

Comment: @mernst shame that there is no way to make a rule, that would ignore only specific error codes for classes having name with a given pattern (something similar to sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria). This really makes working with generated code complicated.

Comment: I agree that is a limitation, exposed by the specific case of generated code where the generator has its own limitations regarding annotations.  Feel free to submit a pull request to extend the scope of Checker Framework warning suppressions.  Thanks!